# How to flip last name and first name using one line of code?

Tags: python

I need to change the variable m_name to become 'Patrick, Sasha' only using one line of code. This is what I have so far but I am not getting the correct output. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

```
name = "Sasha Patrick"

m_name = name.split()[::-1].join(',')

print(m_name)
```

Comment: You have the join function backward.  Try `','.join(name.split()[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You have the join function backward.  Try:

```
m_name = ', '.join(name.split()[::-1])
```

or

```
m_name = ', '.join(reversed(name.split())
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct so it shows up in the listings.